# Chamar script PYTHON através do PHP

Tags: php, python

Quero que o PHP mostre o resultado do código PYTHON

PYTHON

```
x = 4 * 5
print(x)
```

PHP

```
<?php
$teste = shell_exec('python codigopython.py 2>&1');
echo $teste; ?>
```

O Resultado que estou recebendo é:

> 'python' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um
>   programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Mas se eu executo o código python no CMD, funciona normalmente

Comment: E onde está seu Python? está onde pode ser acessado universalmente pelo sistema operacional?

Comment: está junto com o index.php no caminho: C:\wamp64\www\teste-php-python\codigopython.py 
já tentei usar o 'shell_exec' com o caminho, mas da o mesmo resultado.
shell_exec('python C:\wamp64\www\teste-php-python\codigopython.py 2>&1');

'python' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Caio, acredito que a pergunta era se o seu interpretador de Python é acessível, não se o seu script escrito em Python é acessível.

Comment: user140828, acho que sim, pois o 'shell_exec' está conseguindo ir até o código em python, mas na hora de executar, não está dando certo.

Comment: Se deu o erro citado, o Windows não está localizando o interpretador Python na sua máquina - então ele nem "chega ir até o código". Verifique se o executável do Python está na sua variável de ambiente PATH ou execute passando o caminho absoluto do interpretador.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson Carlos Woss, o PATH está correto, mas só funcionou passando o caminho absoluto do interpretador.

Answer (score -2):

Use isso

```
<?php

$comando = escapeshellcmd('./ficheiro_python.py');
$cmdResult = shell_exec($comando);
echo $cmdResult;

?>
```

Como linha "shebang" deverás ter o seguinte no ficheiro python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Também deverás ter permissões para executar esse ficheiro.

Testado com sucesso com o Ubuntu 16, PHP7.0 e python 2.7.